# Android: Publish ads on mobile app which runs in background?

Tags: android, mobile, ads, publisher

I have an android mobile app which runs in the background. Can I still serve ads while the app  is running as a background service? Basically to monetize.

Comment: Um, the user needs to see the ads for them to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just make your background service that start a new activity which shows your ad.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called airpush.
It is not the nicest thing to do to monetize a program, because it is tantamount to pop-up ads on the phone.
There are tools that will detect programs that airpush and recommend them for deletion.
Instead, I would recommend splash screen ads and ads small banners in your config menus.

See this http://androidforums.com/android-applications/452862-list-apps-using-airpush.html as to the general attitude on airpush.

See this http://www.airpush.com/android-developers/ on how to airpush.